# PFObject does not reflect "successfully" saved changes in the Parse Data Browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to update a `PFObject` called `message`. This `PFObject` has already been retrieved from the Parse Database and passed over from another view controller. I know that the `PFObject` is passed over correctly because I can `NSLog` it's value and it is correct.

With the following code, I add an object to one of the `PFObject's` keys:

```
[self.message addObject:@"blah" forKey:@"didRespond"];
```

I then try saving the updated `PFObject` to the Parse Database:

```
[self.message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"An error has occurred.");
        } 
}];
```

The above method always calls back with a `succeeded` value of 1, and there are never any errors. However, when I go and look at the `PFObject` in the Parse Data Browser, it's key does not contain the newly added object. It is still completely empty.

They key is an array, so I know I should be using `addObject:` and not `setObject:`

I have several other Parse saves happening in this same view controller, and throughout my app, and they all work perfectly fine, but for some reason this one will not. I have tried every type of save method Parse offers, including the synchronous `save` method, but nothing works.

What is even more strange, is this is a new version of my app and I am refactoring the code. My old version contains a giant mess of code, but what's amazing is the same `PFObject` is successfully updated in this old code! I even tried copying and pasting this code to my new version and it will not work, even though it will in the old version.

Here is the giant mess of code from my old version. If you search for the following code statement you will be able to locate it quickly:

```
[self.message addObject:currentUsersObjectId forKey:@"didRespond"];
```

Here is the full chunk of code, where the save is working and being reflected in the Data Browser. It consists of several nested asynchronous Parse saves:

```
-(void)uploadPhoto {

    NSLog(@"self.image.size right before upload: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.image.size));

    NSString *fileType;
    NSString *halfOrFull;


    if(self.image != nil) {

        fileType = @"image";
        halfOrFull = @"full";

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 0.7);

        PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imageData];


        NSString *originalSender = [[NSString alloc]init];

        originalSender = [self.message objectForKey:@"senderId"];






        NSLog(@"PFFile has been created: %@", imageFile);

        [imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

            if(error) {

                NSLog(@"There has been an error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"An error occurred!" message:@"Please try sending your message again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                [alertView show];

            } else {


                [self.afterPhotoView setHidden:YES];





                PFObject *returnMessage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Messages"];
                [returnMessage setObject:imageFile forKey:@"file"];
                [returnMessage setObject:fileType forKey:@"fileType"];
                [returnMessage addObject:originalSender forKey:@"recipientIds"];
                [returnMessage setObject:[[PFUser currentUser]objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
                [returnMessage setObject:[[PFUser currentUser]username]forKey:@"senderName"];
                [returnMessage setObject:halfOrFull forKey:@"halfOrFull"];

                NSString *originalSender = [[NSString alloc]init];

                originalSender = [self.message objectForKey:@"senderName"];

                [returnMessage setObject:originalSender forKey:@"originalSender"];

                [returnMessage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                    if(error) {

                        NSLog(@"There was an error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

                        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"An error occurred!" message:@"Please try sending your message again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                        [alertView show];

                    } else {

                        //Everything was successful.

                        NSLog(@"Everything was successful.");



                        if(succeeded == 1) {

                            NSLog(@"Succeeded value right before 2nd save: %d", succeeded);


                            NSString *currentUsersObjectId = [[NSString alloc]init];


                            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

                            currentUsersObjectId = user.objectId;

                            [self.message addObject:currentUsersObjectId forKey:@"didRespond"];

                            [self.message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {


                                if(error) {

                                    NSLog(@"There was an error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

                                    self.uploadPhotoAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"An error occurred!" message:@"Please try sending your message again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                                    [self.uploadPhotoAlertView show];



                                } else {



                                    //Everything was successful.

                                    NSLog(@"Everything was successful.");






                                    if(succeeded == 1) {


                                        //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToInbox" sender:self];


                                        NSString *originalSender2 = [[NSString alloc]init];

                                        originalSender2 = [self.message objectForKey:@"senderName"];

                                        self.photoUploadAlertViewMessage = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You just finished going halfsies with %@!", originalSender2];

                                        //PFFile *imageFile = [self.message objectForKey:@"file"];

                                        self.finishedImageFile = imageFile;

                                        self.finishedImageFileURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:self.finishedImageFile.url];

                                        self.uploadPhotoAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:self.photoUploadAlertViewMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Sweet!" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                                        [self.uploadPhotoAlertView show];

                                        //[self.sharePhotoView setHidden:NO];


                                    }


                                    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToInbox" sender:self];


                                }




                            }];






                        }








                    }



                }];
            }



        }];

    }



}
```

Comment: Have you checked the log on the parse.com dashboard?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the log"?

Comment: Under cloud code on your dashboard.  You can also define a cloud code before save trigger to log the request

Comment: I have checked the cloud code logs section, both in "Info" and "Error", and there is nothing recent.

Comment: "You can also define a cloud code before save trigger to log the request" - Are you talking about this? https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#logging

Comment: Yes, that combined with the section on "running code on save"

Comment: If you would be willing to submit an answer with how I should add the logging and running code on save features in my Cloud Code file I will gladly accept the answer because I don't know javascript.