# Need to run code on save and log from Parse Cloud Code when updating PFObject's key in iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I have a `PFObject` that has an array key. I can successfully call `addObject:` on this `PFObject`, and can confirm that the object has been added to the array key properly using an `NSLog`. However, when I try to save the `PFObject` to Parse, even though it says everything went successful, the changes are not shown in the Data Browser.

I have tried everything, and can even get this to work in an older version of my app, but for some reason it will not work anymore.

I posted another StackOverflow question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718404/pfobject-does-not-reflect-successfully-saved-changes-in-the-parse-data-browser)

The only response I got were some comments saying that I should trigger a "before save" function and log everything via Cloud Code. The problem is I don't know javascript, and I've been messing around with Cloud Code and nothing's happening.

Here is the code I am executing in my app:

```
[self.message addObject:currentUsersObjectId forKey:@"myArrayKey"];
```

And then I am using `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:`

I need to alter Cloud Code so that it will check the `self.message` object's `"myArrayKey"` before saving and log the results.

Edit 2:

Here is how I create currentUsersObjectId:

```
NSString *currentUsersObjectId = [[NSString alloc]init];

PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

currentUsersObjectId = user.objectId;
```

Edit 3:

Here is the save block

```
[self.message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"An error has occurred.");
    } 
}];
```

Edit 4:

After adding Timothy's cloud code, the `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` now does not successfully complete. Instead an error occurs, and the error object NSLogs as `"Error: Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object. (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.17)" and also as:

```
Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 141.)" UserInfo=0x15dc4550 {code=141, error=Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object.} {
    code = 141;
    error = "Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object.";
}
```

Here is my complete Cloud Code file after adding Timothy's code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('editUser', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId;
        //newColText = request.params.newColText;

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
        user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    var currentUser = request.user;

    var relation = user.relation("friendsRelation");
    relation.add(currentUser);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Messages", function(request, response) {
    var message = request.object;

    // output just the ID so we can check it in the Data Browser
    console.log("Saving message with ID:", message.id);
    // output the whole object so we can see all the details including "didRespond"
    console.log(message);

    response.success();
});

// log the after-save too, to confirm it was saved
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Messages", function(request, response) {
    var message = request.object;

    // output just the ID so we can check it in the Data Browser
    console.log("Saved message with ID:", message.id);
    // output the whole object so we can see all the details including "didRespond"
    console.log(message);

    response.success();
});
```

Comment: Please show your full code that saves, the logging comments on your other question were suggestions to help you debug the issue. Also please give details of the column types (is `myArrayKey` of type `Array<string>` or `Array<_User>` etc).

Comment: Need to see your iOS code (from where you get `currentUsersObjectId` to your save block), you can remove that Cloud Code from your question as it is completely unrelated.

Comment: Please see my second edit.

Comment: .. and the full save block? So far everything looks fine (as long as there is a current user). Consider placing NSLog statements everywhere to confirm that everything is as expected (user, currentUsersOjbectId, self.message, success/error code etc).

Comment: I just added the save block. I have already NSLogged everything. Succeeded comes back as true, no error, everything NSLogs. Even before saving, if I NSLog self.message it shows the value added to the key. It makes no sense.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it isn't working? Can you tell me how to log and do the before save in cloud code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much back and forth, I'm stumped as to why this isn't working for you. As for logging in Cloud Code, if you follow the guide on adding code you can add the following to your main.js and deploy it:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Messages", function(request, response) {
    var message = request.object;

    // output just the ID so we can check it in the Data Browser
    console.log("Saving message with ID:", message.id);
    // output the whole object so we can see all the details including "didRespond"
    console.log(message);

    response.success();
});

// log the after-save too, to confirm it was saved
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Messages", function(request, response) {
    var message = request.object;

    // output just the ID so we can check it in the Data Browser
    console.log("Saved message with ID:", message.id);
    // output the whole object so we can see all the details including "didRespond"
    console.log(message);

    response.success();
});
```

With those in place you have plenty of server-side logging that you can check.

Comment: Hey, please see the edit I added called Edit 4. I changed my cloud code file based on your answer and now saveInBackgroundWithBlock is no longer working.

Comment: Right, now we're finally getting the real error. You need to list every property you're setting on that "Messages" class, as one of them ins't saved yet and is causing a problem.

Comment: I actually just figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding my own answer in addition to Timothy's in case anyone else is having a problem similar to this. My app uses the following library to allow parse objects to be stored using `NSUserDefaults`: https://github.com/eladb/Parse-NSCoding

For whatever reason, after unarchiving the parse objects, they are not able to be saved properly to the Parse database. I had to query the database using the unarchived one's objectId and retrieve a fresh version of the object, and then I was able to successfully make changes to and save the retrieved object.

I have no idea why this is happening now. I have never had any problems until about two weeks ago when I tried to deploy a new version of my cloud code, and if I remember correctly, Parse wanted me to update the Parse SDK or the Cloud Code version before I could deploy it.

These changes must not be compatible with these categories.